# Is that possible that two different product of same vendor show different pair of devicename, vid, pid?

Tags: operating-system

Currently i am thinking for a functionality for devices which has to rely on identification of unique devices. Currently i am thinking to keep device name also in that list as a measure to identify uniqueness of device.

My question is : Will ever be a case ever that a manufacturer has two product having same vid, different pid but same name ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to uniquely identify specific devices, use the VID, PID, *and serial number* if available. This will allow you to sometimes tell two instances of the same device apart, like two flash drives or USB serial adapters.

I wouldn't use the device name -- if the VID and PID of two devices are the same, the devices will almost always have the same name, so using it is unlikely to make much of a difference.

> Will ever be a case ever that a manufacturer has two product having same vid, different pid but same name ?

This is a slightly different question. Yes, this will happen sometimes, typically in situations where a product name is somewhat generic. (For instance, a manufacturer of flash drives will probably have many different devices all with their VID and the name "USB Flash Drive", but different PIDs.)